# How can I fix ClassNotFounException when executing HBase java application from command line?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hbase

I don't know anything about bash, but i put together a script to help me run my Hbase java application:

```
#!/bin/bash

HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$(hbase classpath)"
hadoop jar my.jar my_pkg.my_class
```

When I run it I get a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/IncreasingToUpperBoundRegionSplitPolicy
```

When I echo out the HADOOP_CLASSPATH I see that hbase-server-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar is there...

Is the `hadoop jar` command ignoring the HADOOP_CLASSPATH?

---

Also I have tried to run the commands from the command-line instead of using my script.  I get the same error.

---

The approach was inspired by this [cloduera-question](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Hadoop-101-Training-Quickstart/Trying-to-run-simple-Java-Hbase-program-w-Eclipse/td-p/6853)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include the Hadoop class path on the same line.  I am not certain what the difference is, but this works:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$(hbase classpath)" hadoop jar my.jar my_pkg.my_class
```

Comment: This is because of a confusing aspect of bash shell variables - there's a different scope for variables in the shell vs. something called "the environment".  When a new shell starts, all the environment variables are basically copied and become shell variables.

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$(hbase classpath)" ; 
hadoop jar my.jar my_pkg.my_class

Would work, because the new process started in the hadoop command will have the classpath automatically copied from the environment.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference